# regex, capture a line not containing sub-string conditionally

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

my code is parsing some lines in a log file.

i do many things with this, but a particular need has come up to be able to find a line which does not contain a certain sub-string. under a certain condition

i have a pretty good understanding of regular expressions. but i cant seem to figure this one out.

the problem:
i want to capture any line which does not contain the word `error` or `warn`. unless it is the first part of the log entry and surrounded with square brackets.

so far, i have tried something like this:

```
(((?:abc|cba)\s+.*(?!\[?(?!error|warn)\]?).*)|((abc|cba)\s+\[(error|warn)\]\s+(.*)))
```

the lines in the log can look like some of these examples:

**capture group 2**:

```
abc [error] message
cba [error] message
cba [warn] message
```

**capture group 1**:

```
abc something random
cba i dont know
```

**don't capture**:

```
abc some [error] message
cba some [warn] message
```

the problem in simpler English; I want to get any line which starts with `abc` or `cba`. capture group 1 should grab the line if it doesn't have `[error]` or `[warn]` anywhere in it. and capture group 2 should get it only if `[error]` or `[warn]` are the first part of the entry (after the `abc` or `cba`)

Comment: So the regex is supposed to work in 1 line only? As in you pass lines one by one to the regex to check?

Comment: @nhahtdh each line of the file gets parsed by the regex. 1 by 1. yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
^(?:abc|cba)(?:(?!.*(?:\[error\]|\[warn\]))|\s*(?:\[error\]|\[warn\])).*$
```

Note that I assert the whole line to match the regex with `^` and `$`.

I first check for `abc` and `cba` starting the line.

Then 2 cases:

- Neither `[error]` nor `[warn]` appear anywhere in the line: `(?!.*(?:\[error\]|\[warn\]))` (The `?:` is not very important, just non-capturing group).
- Or `[error]` or `[warn]` follow right after `abc` and `cba`: `\s*(?:\[error\]|\[warn\])`. Note that you may want to change `\s*` to `\s+`, since current regex will match `abc[error]`.

Then the rest I don't care `.*`, but it needs to be there, since I used `$`. I'm not totally sure about Python: check whether you can remove `.*$` part of the regex.

I make all groups non-capturing, since you seem to be asserting that the line follow certain format. If you need to extract some data from the line at the same time, let me know.

Comment: thanks so much. your solution helped me find what worked for mine.
if interested, i am currently going with: `((?:abc|cba)(?!.*(?:\[(?:error|warn)\]).*).*)|((abc|cba)\s+\[(error|warn)\]\s+(.*))` - the thing that made it work was including the `.*` inside the negative lookahead (`(?!)`) :) http://regexr.com?32db0

Comment: @InbarRose: I'm not sure which function you are using, but check this case: `"sfdkjsfhk abc [error] askdjhaksd"` - should be rejected.

Comment: yes - i know, but this is only a part of the main regular expression. which cases different things. thanks for your concern. i was just trying to figure out specifically how to ignore lines with that specific format, after all the rest of my work. - also - i linked the wrong regex - it should be http://regexr.com?32db3